# Submultiplicity of Induced Norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

This is a lecture note on induced norms from Cornell: [pdf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs6210-f09/lec03.pdf)

Given $A$ is a matrix and $v$ is a vector with length less than or equal to $1$. It says, "if $||\cdot||$ is an induced norm, then $||Av||\leq ||A||\cdot||v||$ from the definition of vector norms."

I check all definitions on Wikipedia, but could not figure out why. Is there any hint or comment? I don't think vector norms have such properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let me write your inequality when $v \ne 0$ as

$$\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}\le \|A\|$$

Comment: If I change "$||v||=1$" to "$||v||\leq1$" in the definition of induced norms, will we still have such inequality?

Comment: maximizing $\|Av\|$ over $\{v: \|v\|=1\}$ is equal to maximizing $\|Av\|$ over $\{v: \|v\|\le 1\}$. Use the property that $\|cv\|=|c|\|v\|$ to prove it.

Comment: hmm...the question used $\|.\|$ for both vector norm and induced norm.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, I think they just mean 'from the definition of induced norm'. Since the norm of $A$ is defined as the supremum, we have inequality for all $v \in V$.